# OpenMP issue : nested loops in fortran

Tags: loops, nested, fortran, openmp

I have an issue with the following code, in fortran. I just want to transfer a 4 dimensionnal array to a 3-d one and I can't inverse the order of the loops for other reasons. I want the 3 internal loops only to be parallels in an OpenMP environment.

```
 PROGRAM TEST

   USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTEGER(INT32), SAVE :: ii,i,j,k,lx,ly,lz

   REAL(REAL64),DIMENSION(:,:,:,:),ALLOCATABLE,SAVE :: tab4
   REAL(REAL64),DIMENSION(  :,:,:),ALLOCATABLE,SAVE :: tab3 

   ALLOCATE(...)
   CALL INITIALIZE_TO_ZERO_ALL_TABS       

   $OMP PARALLEL
   DO ii=1,6

      !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(RUNTIME)
      DO k=0,lz-1
        DO j=0,ly-1
          DO i=0,lx-1                    !<-- flagged error lign
            tab3(i,j,k) = tab4(ii,i,j,k)
          END DO
        END DO
      END DO
      !$OMP END DO

      CALL SOME_SUBROUTINE(tab3)

    END DO

    !$OMP END PARALLEL

  END PROGRAM TEST
```

The compilation is ok. But the following error message pops up at the execution : *"Fortran runtime error: Loop variable has been modified"*.

It seems that there is an issue between ii, which appears in tab4(ii,i,j,k), and OpenMP. For information, this issue desappear when I compile without -fopenmp.

Do you have any idea of what's going on in those simple nested loops ?

Comment: Where do you start your parallel region? What is the scoping of your variables?

Comment: @francescalus eps_voigt is a 4 dimension table with profile (6,lx,ly,lz)
tab7 is a 3 dimension table with profile (lx,ly,lz)

Comment: @IanBush the parallel region is started before, elsewhere in the code. There is no issue with loops in the code before these nested loops.

Comment: We really need to see a [mcve].  There can't really be an issue in the 'code' you have shown us because it is not really code, it's pseudo-code.  Also, does your system not tell you which line the run-time error occurs at ?

Comment: @benoitdabas That is not what I was asking, we need to see your variable scoping - what is shared and what is private?

Comment: For everyone, I edited my code so that it's better for you

Comment: Now consider the OpenMP data accessibility attributes `shared` and `private`, and consider which variables in your program should have one or the other attribute, and which ones in fact do.